# How to show that a one-form is closed

Tags: integration, closed-form, line-integrals, exterior-derivative

For $c \colon [0, 2π] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with the helix $c(t) = (\cos t,\sin t, t)$ and the 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$\alpha = 2x_1 x_2 \,dx_1+ (x_1)^2\, dx_2 + x_3\,dx_3$$

How do you find the exterior derivative and show that $dα = 0$?

So far I've got

$$d \alpha  = d(2x_1x_2) \wedge dx_1 + d((x_1)^2) \wedge dx_2 + dx_3 \wedge dx_3$$

so then

$$d \alpha  = d(2x_1x_2) \wedge dx_1 + d((x_1)^2) \wedge dx_2 + 0$$

but I don't know how to make this equal to $0$

Comment: Note that $d(2x_1x_2)=2x_1dx_2 + 2x_2dx_1$ for instance.

Comment: so then it would become $d\alpha = (2x_1 dx_2) \wedge dx_1 + d((x_1)^2) \wedge dx_2$?

Comment: Yes, and you also have a product formula for $d((x_1)^2)$.

Comment: would you be able explain the product formula?

Comment: $d(fg)=fdg+gdf$ for smooth functions $f,g$.

Comment: would $d((x_1)^2)$ then become $x_1 dx_1 +x_1 dx_1$?

Comment: so then it would be $d\alpha = 2x_1 dx_2 \wedge dx_1 + x_1 dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + x_1 dx_1 \wedge dx_2 $?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: thank you for your help so far but how would this then equal zero?

Comment: When $a,b$ are $1$-forms, $a\wedge b=-b \wedge a$. I strongly suggest that you review your lecture notes (or the reference material), it seems that you haven’t quite understood it.

Comment: thank you I understand more now